# mingw in eclipse make error 1

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, mingw

Trying to build a cpp program in eclipse, i run into make:*** Error 1
looking at the console I get the following:

```
make all 
Building target: mrconvert
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++ -LC:\GnuWin32\lib\ -o "mrconvert"  ./src/mrconvert.o   -llibgsl
g++.exe: error: mrconvert: No such file or directory
make: *** [mrconvert] Error 1
```

mrconvert is the name of the cpp program i am trying to compile.. why do I receive an error that the file or directory does not exist?

Edit:

By changing the toolchain from Cross GCC to MinGW GCC I no longer get the Make Error 1 described above. However I now get a nice new list of errors:

```
11:42:55 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project mrconv ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:\\Users\\Jesse\\Documents\\Work\\Research\\FiberTracking\\Software\\mrtrix\\source\\mrtrix-0.2.11\\lib" "-IC:\\Users\\Jesse\\Programs\\gtk+\\lib" "-IC:\\Users\\Jesse\\Programs\\gtk+\\bin" "-IC:\\Users\\Jesse\\Programs\\gtk+\\include\\glib-2.0" "-IC:\\Users\\Jesse\\Programs\\gtk+\\lib\\glib-2.0\\include" "-IC:\\gtkmm64\\include\\glibmm-2.4\\glibmm" "-IC:\\gtkmm64\\include\\glibmm-2.4" "-IC:\\gtkmm64\\lib\\glibmm-2.4\\include" "-IC:\\gtkmm64\\include\\sigc++-2.0" "-IC:\\gtkmm64\\lib\\sigc++-2.0\\include" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuWin32\\include" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuWin32\\include\\gsl" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\mrconvert.o" "..\\src\\mrconvert.cpp" 
g++ "-LC:\\GnuWin32\\lib\\" -o mrconv.exe "src\\mrconvert.o" -llibgsl 
src\mrconvert.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug/../src/mrconvert.cpp:119: undefined reference to `MR::App::run(int, char**)'
src\mrconvert.o: In function `ZN5MyApp7executeEv':
C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug/../src/mrconvert.cpp:123: undefined reference to `MR::parse_floats(std::string const&)'
C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug/../src/mrconvert.cpp:167: undefined reference to `MR::DataType::parse(std::string const&)'
C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug/../src/mrconvert.cpp:174: undefined reference to `MR::Image::parse_axes_specifier(MR::Image::Axes const&, std::string const&)'
C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug/../src/mrconvert.cpp:201: undefined reference to `MR::parse_ints(std::string const&, int)'
C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug/../src/mrconvert.cpp:225: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::init(unsigned int, std::string const&)'
src\mrconvert.o: In function `_static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug/../src/mrconvert.cpp:55: undefined reference to `MR::Argument::End'
C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug/../src/mrconvert.cpp:95: undefined reference to `MR::Option::End'
src\mrconvert.o: In function `ZNK2MR9Exception7displayEv':
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:187: undefined reference to `MR::Exception::level_offset'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:187: undefined reference to `MR::error'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:188: undefined reference to `MR::Exception::level_offset'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:188: undefined reference to `MR::info'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:189: undefined reference to `MR::debug'
src\mrconvert.o: In function `ZN2MR11ProgressBar3incEv':
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:451: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::current_val'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:451: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::current_val'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:452: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::display'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:452: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::stop'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:453: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::multiplier'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:453: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::stop_watch'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:453: undefined reference to `Glib::Timer::elapsed() const'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:453: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::current_val'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:453: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::multiplier'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:454: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::percent'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:455: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::percent'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:456: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::display_func'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:458: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::stop'
src\mrconvert.o: In function `ZN2MR11ProgressBar4doneEv':
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:461: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::display'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/mrtrix.h:461: undefined reference to `MR::ProgressBar::done_func'
src\mrconvert.o: In function `ZN2MR5Image6ObjectD1Ev':
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/image/object.h:49: undefined reference to `MR::info'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/image/object.h:49: undefined reference to `MR::Image::Mapper::unmap(MR::Image::Header const&)'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/image/object.h:49: undefined reference to `MR::Image::Mapper::~Mapper()'
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/image/object.h:49: undefined reference to `MR::Image::Mapper::~Mapper()'
src\mrconvert.o: In function `ZN2MR5Image6Object3mapEv':
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/image/object.h:57: undefined reference to `MR::Image::Mapper::map(MR::Image::Header const&)'
src\mrconvert.o: In function `ZNK2MR7ArgBase9get_imageERNS_5Image6HeaderE':
C:/Users/Jesse/Documents/Work/Research/FiberTracking/Software/mrtrix/source/mrtrix-0.2.11/lib/args.h:201: undefined reference to `MR::Image::Object::create(std::string const&, MR::Image::Header&)'
src\mrconvert.o: In function `ZN5MyAppC1EiPPcPPKcPKN2MR8ArgumentEPKNS5_6OptionEPKjS3_S3_':
C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug/../src/mrconvert.cpp:119: undefined reference to `MR::App::App(int, char**, char const**, MR::Argument const*, MR::Option const*, unsigned int const*, char const*, char const*)'
src\mrconvert.o: In function `ZN5MyAppD1Ev':
C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug/../src/mrconvert.cpp:119: undefined reference to `MR::App::~App()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

11:42:57 Build Finished (took 1s.854ms)
```

How do I go about solving these linking errors?

Much appreciated!

Jesse

Comment: That's a rather strange error message given the circumstances. I wonder if it's trying to say that you don't have permissions to create `mrconvert`.

Comment: I changed the name of the project to see what would happen, and i get this

    'Building target: mrconv'
    'Invoking: Cross G++ Linker'
    'g++ -LC:\GnuWin32\lib\ -o "mrconv"  ./src/mrconvert.o   -llibgsl'
    'g++.exe: error: mrconv: No such file or directory'
    'make: *** [mrconv] Error 1'

so it does appear that the output directory is giving my a problem, such as missing permissions, however I am working in windows, why would I get missing permissions?

Comment: What happens if you run the offending command from the command prompt, as opposed to from `make`?

Comment: I am able to run C:\Users\Jesse\workspace\mrconv\Debug>g++ -LC:\GnuWin32\lib\ -o "mrconv.exe"  ./src/mrconvert.o   -llibgsl  and I get a bunch of linking errors. 

any idea how I can correct the file not fould in eclipse?